# Making a sports league-like group creator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, I'm trying to make a "group creator" that works by pressing a button to create a group every time I press it and then it lets me create each group "slots" with the function below.

I attached a drawing showing how the end result should look like, but I can't find a way around it. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iCnt = 0;

    var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
        padding: '5px', margin: '20px', width: '170px', border: '1px dashed',
        borderTopColor: '#999', borderBottomColor: '#999',
        borderLeftColor: '#999', borderRightColor: '#999'
    });
    
    $('#btAdd').click(function() {
        if (iCnt <= 19) {
            
            iCnt = iCnt + 1;
            
            // Añadir caja de texto.
            $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
            'value="Text Element ' + iCnt + '" />');
            
            if (iCnt == 1) {   
                
                var divSubmit = $(document.createElement('div'));
                $(divSubmit).append('<input type=button class="bt" onclick="GetTextValue()"' + 
                'id=btSubmit value=Enviar />');
                
            }
            
            $('#main').after(container, divSubmit); 
        }
        else {
            
            $(container).append('<label>Limit Reached</label>'); 
            $('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt-disable'); 
            $('#btAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <input type="button" id="btAdd" value="Add Slot" class="bt" />
    <input type="button" id="btRemove" value="Remove Slot" class="bt" />
    <input type="button" id="btRemoveAll" value="Remove Group" class="bt" /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is without running the code, could you be more clear what you are trying to "get around" please?

Comment: I think it's necessary to run the code to understand. Basically I want a button that can create a group (like in the image) every time I press it and each group runs the function in the code attached.

Comment: so what is the actual issue?

Comment: Your `$(container).append` is already adding dynamic HTML elements to the page. Try to modify that to append not only an input box, but to add the whole box like you want from your picture. Something like `$(container).append("<div class='myGroupBox'>{Your group content here}</div>")`